# How to play MediaElement in background.?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing an application to play online radio via streaming. I have used MediaElement. But the problem is the **player doesn't play in background**. I mean as soon as I click on  "start" or "back" button on the phone, the streaming as well as the audio stops. **I have not tested it on any device, so please inform me if it does happen in simulator but not device.** Here is my code..

```
private void Play()
    {
        if (mediaElement == null || mediaElement.CurrentState != MediaElementState.Playing)
        {
            if (SystemTray.ProgressIndicator == null)
                SystemTray.ProgressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();

            SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsIndeterminate = true;
            SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsVisible = true;
            SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.Text = "Connecting to *********...";

            mediaStream = new ********.RadioStream(uri);


            mediaStream.StreamSetupComplete += (o, e) =>
            {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    if (mediaElement != null)
                    {
                        LayoutRoot.Children.Remove(mediaElement);
                    }
                    mediaElement = new MediaElement();
                    mediaElement.Volume = 1.0;
                    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(mediaElement);
                    mediaElement.SetSource(mediaStream);

                    SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsVisible = false;
                });
            };
        }
    }
```

I want to know the steps to enable this to play in background. Atleast when the user presses "start" button, the audio streaming should not stop.

Also one more problem I have is I have added an ApplicationBarMenu in which I have an "Exit" button. As soon as the user clicks this button the streaming should stop and **application should close itself**. I am unable to close the application programmatically. Code is give below..

```
 void exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (playing)
        {
            MessageBoxResult Choice;
            Choice = MessageBox.Show("Media is currently playing, do you want to stop it?", "Stop Player", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
            if (Choice == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
                ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();
                brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images/play.png", UriKind.Relative));
                play.Background = brush;
                Stop();
                playing = false;
                try
                {

                //    if (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
                //    {
                //        while (NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry() != null)
                //        {
                //            NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
                //        }
                //    }
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }

            else
            {

            }
          }

        }
```

Please help me with the proper code. Even if there is any other way to stream media in background other than MediaElement, please suggest that too.. 
Hoping a reply soon. Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: Please someone answer this question. I am in deep trouble due to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use [BackgroundAudioPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio.backgroundaudioplayer%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for this.

You should take a look at [Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundAudio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) Namespace too.