# BackgroundAudioPlayer in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1, background-audio

Is there any explanation about playing an audio from URL in windows phone in background using BackgroundAudioPlayer.? Why has it to be so complex to code this thing in Windows Phone. Can I get any code, any example, any explanation, any sample, any preview, anywhere which can give a proper explanation about this.? Please someone explain or help me with some good link to its explanation.

Comment: Could you please describe the problem you're having with BAP and what you've tried so far to solve it?

Comment: @paul .. Actually I am using mediaElement to stream my audio via URL. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790927/how-to-play-mediaelement-in-background) is the code. As you can see I got the suggestion to use BackgroundAudioPlayer. But the problem is that I am getting more and more confused with this player. I just want some example to good explanation link for it as I have tried my best ending up with nothing at all.

Comment: have a look at this post [audioplayeragent timer and webservice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702935/audioplayeragent-timer-and-webservice/9710014#9710014)

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample for playing background audio from a URI at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978(v=vs.105).aspx

I found this very useful when I first did it.

Comment: but this doesn't play song from URL. Its a file stored internally. I don't want that, I want it to be played online via URL.

Comment: @Akshat The sample uses a local file as an example but works exactly the same way when working with a remote file. The point of the sample is it's playing from a URI. It can be a local or remote one.