# Audio streaming in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, audio-streaming, mediaelement

I'm new to windows phone 8.

**In my application I am getting the audio file path from the server. Now when the user clicks on listen button in my app, then I have to play that audio file.**

For example: **http://traffic.libsyn.com/wpradio/WPRadio_29.mp3**

What are the different ways to play the above audio file.

Thanks

Comment: Check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394039(v=vs.105).aspx and http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Background-Audio-Streamer-e85b8deb

Comment: I have an audio file on the server location. Now when the user clicks on the play button in my application then I have to play that audio file. Can we play that audio file using MediaElement?

Comment: did you get any answers?

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I wouldn't do that with MediaElemnt - it will work, but not in Background - [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790927/how-to-play-mediaelement-in-background).
Much better option is to play it with [Background Audio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394039(v=vs.105).aspx) and [AudioStreamingAgent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio.audiostreamingagent(v=vs.105).aspx). Here you have [one blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpukcoe/archive/2012/02/11/background-audio-in-windows-phone-7-5-part-3.aspx) where you can find usefull information. There are also many [examples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Background-Audio-Streamer-e85b8deb).

Comment: Hi romasz, I am new to windows phone development.Could you please help me how to play an audio file(which is in remote location) through MediaElement.

Comment: I've found something which should work: http://studentguru.gr/academics/communities/b/larissa/archive/2012/10/23/mediaelement-39-s-methods-play-pause-stop-in-windows-8-do-not-work-for-live-streaming.aspx - there is xaml line which looks good, thought I've not tested it - there is also one problem solved which may help you. If you still want to do it with MediaElement :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can play it with MediaElement.
You must have audio uri path.

```
MediaElement remotePlayer= new MediaElement();
remotePlayer.AutoPlay=true;
//FileName is your remote uri
 remotePlayer.Source = new Uri(FileName, UriKind.Absolute);
                    remotePlayer.Play();
```